# whats yardoc syntax for linking to models that are in a namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, yard

I couldn't find it anywhere on their website.

Here is what I have:

```
# {Page::Section}
```

but when i run the yardoc generation, I get this error:

```
[warn]: In file `app/controllers/pages_controller.rb':2: Cannot resolve link to Page::Section from text:
[warn]: ...{Page::Section}...
```

and when I go to the api page where my documentation above is written, it just shows plain text, and not a link to that object's page.

I suspect though, that the above error is because it never found this class:

```
class Page::Section < ActiveRecord::Base
```

(but If I change it to PageSection, the docs render just fine).

Maybe it has something to do with the version of [yard-rest-plugin](https://github.com/DerNalia/yard-rest-plugin/) i'm using?
I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with namespaced controllers. I was frustrated but it ended up being user error.

Assuming `class Inherited::ResourceController < InheritedController`

`{Inherited::ResourceController#show}` will work, but `{InheritedController::ResourceController#show}` will not. (See, I told you it was user error)

Comment: Hi @aseroff you're answering a question which is over 8 years old. Please try to answer new questions, this is more helpful.